# $\frac {1}{2n+1}<\frac {1}{n^2+1}+\frac {1}{n^2+2}+\cdots+\frac {1}{n^2+n}<\frac {1}{2n}$

Tags: inequality

Given that $n \in \mathbf Z$ and also $n\ge 2$

show that -

$$\frac {1}{2n+1}<\frac {1}{n^2+1}+\frac {1}{n^2+2}+\cdots+\frac {1}{n^2+n}<\frac {1}{2n}$$

No idea about this. Please help.

Comment: What are the smallest and the largest term in the sum?

Comment: @DanielFischer I didn't get you sir

Comment: Presumably you mean $n\ge2$, not $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @BarryCipra how?

Comment: Try plugging in $n = 0$ and see whether the first inequality is true.

Comment: @JohnHughes : Plugging in $n=0$ may be a bit subtle: in that case, the number of terms is $0$, so the sum is $0$.  If $n=1$, then there's just one term, and it says $\dfrac 1 {2\cdot1+1} < \dfrac 1 {1^2+1} < \dfrac 1 {2\cdot 1}$, which isn't quite true.  So Barry Cipra is right. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I don't think it's true for $n=2$, either.

Comment: How to solve it then?

Comment: @user84413, you're quite right.  I only noticed that $1/2\not<1/2$ when $n=1$.

Comment: Surely the limits are $1/(n+1)$ and $1/n$?  Then it's true for $n > 0$ and fairly easy to prove.

Comment: @BrianTung I think you must be right.

Comment: Good point, @MichaelHardy. I was going to suggest plugging in $n = 10$, which in turn shows that the second inequality is wrong, but OP's responses suggest that might not have been useful. Of course, they also suggest that about $n = 0$. :(

Comment: The right-side inequality is actually "upside down."

Answer (score 2):

We can show that the right-side inequality should actually be reversed by simply observing that for $n\ge 1$ we have

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n^2+k}- \frac{1}{2n}&=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{n^2+k}-\frac{1}{2n^2}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n^2-k}{2n^2(n^2+k)}\\\\
&>0
\end{align}$$

Therefore,

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n^2+k}>\frac{1}{2n}>\frac{1}{2n+1}}$$

---

Note that we can easily show that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n^2+k}<\frac1n$$

since we have

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{n^2+k}-
\frac{1}{n^2}\right)&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{-k}{n^2(n^2+k^2)}\\\\
&<0
\end{align}$$

---

And finally, it is easy to show that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n^2+k}\ge \frac{1}{n+1}$$

since $n^2+k\le n^2+n$ and therefore

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n^2+k}&\ge\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n^2+n}\\\\
&=\frac{n}{n^2+n}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{n+1}
\end{align}$$

---

Putting it all together we find that for $n\ge1$

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{1}{2n+1}<\frac{1}{2n}\le \frac{1}{n+1}\le \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n^2+k}<\frac{1}{n}}$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 1):

I'll see how the
integral method works.

We want to bound
$s_n
=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{n^2+k}
$.

First,
$\frac1{n^2+k-1}
> \int_{k-1}^{k} \frac{dx}{n^2+x}
> \frac1{n^2+k}
$.

Summing,
$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{n^2+k-1}
> \sum_{k=1}^n  \int_{k-1}^{k} \frac{dx}{n^2+x}
> \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{n^2+k}
$
or
$s_n+\frac1{n^2}-\frac1{n^2+n}
>   \int_{0}^{n} \frac{dx}{n^2+x}
> s_n
$.

Since
$ \int_{0}^{n} \frac{dx}{n^2+x}
= \int_{n^2}^{n^2+n} \frac{dx}{x}
=\ln(\frac{n^2+n}{n^2})
=\ln(1+1/n)
$,
and
$\frac1{n^2}-\frac1{n^2+n}
=\frac{n}{n^2(n^2+n)}
= \frac{1}{n^2(n+1)}
$,

we have
$$\ln(1+1/n)
> s_n
> \ln(1+1/n)-\frac{1}{n^2(n+1)}
.$$

Now we need to bound $\ln(1+1/n)$.
The easiest way is to
use the usual series:
$\ln(1+1/n)
=\frac1{n}-\frac1{2n^2}+\frac1{3n^3} ...
$.
Since the series is enveloping
(i.e., its value is between
any two consecutive sums),
$\frac1{n}-\frac1{2n^2}
< \ln(1+1/n)
< \frac1{n}-\frac1{2n^2}+\frac1{3n^3}
$.

Therefore,
$$s_n
< \frac1{n}-\frac1{2n^2}+\frac1{3n^3}
< \frac1{n}
$$
and

$\begin{array}\\
s_n 
&>\frac1{n}-\frac1{2n^2}-\frac{1}{n^2(n+1)}\\
&=\frac1{n}\left(1-\frac1{2n}-\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\right)\\
&=\frac1{n}\left(1-\frac{n-1}{2n(n+1)}\right)\\
&>\frac1{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{2(n+1)}\right)\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem should be to show that

$$
\frac{1}{n+1} < \frac{1}{n^2+1}+\frac{1}{n^2+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^2+n}
              < \frac{1}{n}
$$

This can be demonstrated fairly easily by observing that

$$
\frac{n}{n^2+n} < \frac{1}{n^2+1}+\frac{1}{n^2+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^2+n}
                  < \frac{n}{n^2}
$$