# Showing $\lim_{n\to\infty} (\frac{1}{n^2+1} + \frac{1}{n^2+2}+...+\frac{1}{n^2+n}) = \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I need to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} (\frac{1}{n^2+1} + \frac{1}{n^2+2}+...+\frac{1}{n^2+n}) = \frac{1}{2}$ by estimating the upper and lower bounds and showing that the two new sequences have the limes $\frac{1}{2}$.

Could you please help me, because I have absolutely no idea on how to start.

Thank you!

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1026607/42969.

Comment: The limit is 0, and not 1/2. The lower bound is $\frac{n}{n^2+n}$ and the upper one is $\frac{n}{n^2} = {1\over n}$

Comment: [Avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/42969) – there is always *something* to start with. Here you could compute the expression for $n=1, 2, 3, 4$. You might notice that it is $\le \frac 12$ and *decreasing.*

Comment: @merlinberlin1 Check again your question, are you looking for a different limit? Whre did you find this result?

Comment: Perhaps this is what you are actually looking for: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1409415/42969 ?

Comment: no, 1/2 is the limit according to the task.

Comment: @merlinberlin1 Then it is wrong, maybe a typo, where does it come from?